# Как ограничить вывод в цикле foreach, альтернативный вид

Tags: php

Вот в таком варианте нужно.

```
<?php foreach ($array as $item): ?>
 <a><?=$item?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Уточните ваш вопрос

Comment: Сделать `break` когда нужно или тогда, вопрос вообще не понятен. Что в вашем случае означает, ограничить цикл `foreach`?

Comment: В таблице есть 17 наименований категорий, нужно вывести 5. Я начинающий в php, саму конструкцию можете написать. Спасибо!

Comment: @Владимир в sql запрос можно добавить LIMIT 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

```
$array = [1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five', 6 => 'six'];

$c = 1;
foreach($array as $value) {
  echo $value;
  if ($c == 5) break;
  $c++;
}
```

Но лучше ограничить количество извлекаемых данных из базы непосредственно в запросе

Comment: Спасибо! Переделал код. Интересовало, есть ли возможность ограничение вывода массива в альтернативном виде цикла foreach.

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php

```
<?php $mapArray = array_slice($array, 0, 5);?>

     <?php $i=0; foreach ($mapArray as $item): ?>      
         <a><?=$item?></a>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Не нужно использовать `array_slice` в `foreach` (плохая практика, еще и для новичков.)- принято присваивать в переменную и только потом передавать для обхода.

Comment: Да, полностью согласен